# Inserting a CLOB using cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I am trying to insert a CLOB using the following code.

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.setinputsizes(HERP = cx_Oracle.CLOB)

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO myTable (FOO, BAR) VALUES (:FOO, :BAR)", FOO=val1, BAR=val2)
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO myTable2 (HERP) VALUES (:HERP)", HERP=val3) 
#len(HERP) 39097
```

When I run the script WITHOUT `cursor.setinputsizes(HERP = cx_Oracle.CLOB)` it fails on the second query WITH `ValueError: string data too large`, when I run the script with `cursor.setinputsizes(HERP = cx_Oracle.CLOB)` it fails on the first query with `DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number`. The CLOB I am trying to insert contains a code snippet (i.e. it has a lot of semi colons, commas and parenthesis), `"string".decode("ascii")` returns `u'string'`, so unicode isn't the problem... right? I don't know if either of these things are problems. The field in the database is a currently a CLOB, however I have tried it with an NCLOB and the behavior did not change.

I have also tried the field as a BLOB and then used `.encode("hex")` on the value I was inserting, again same behavior.

I have also tried `HERP = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.CLOB)` instead of `cursor.setinputsizes(HERP = cx_Oracle.CLOB)`, same issues.

I've been going through the discussions on the [cx-oracle-users](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.db.cx-oracle/2302) list, but no luck yet.

It works if I use this line `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO myTable2 (HERP) VALUES (:HERP)", HERP="".join(set(val3)).encode("hex"))`, so I don't think it's an issue with the data's content (This is with the BLOB).

How can I use `cx_Oracle` to insert a CLOB into an Oracle database?

Answer (score 5):

There are a few possible solutions:

1. Upgrade cx_Oracle.  I'm not sure which version you're using, but I'm using python 2.7.2 with cx_Oracle 5.1 and I don't get any errors when inserting 150,000 chars into a CLOB column without using setinputsizes at all.
2. Since setinputsizes applies to every subsequent cursor use, just change it between these different cursor.execute statements.

eg:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.setinputsizes(FOO=None, BAR=None)
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO myTable (FOO, BAR) VALUES (:FOO, :BAR)", 
FOO=val1,  BAR=val2)
cursor.setinputsizes(HERP = cx_Oracle.CLOB)
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO myTable2 (HERP) VALUES (:HERP)", HERP=val3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used a json object because I already had the code to cut and paste. I'm sure there's something else to set the text as whatever but eh

```
eh = json.loads(text)
eh[var]=whatever

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO myTable2 (HERP) VALUES (:HERP)", HERP=eh[var])
```