# Large string to clob varible returns PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Tags: string, oracle, buffer, clob, cx-oracle

I am having trouble with the code below.  I keep getting a "numeric or value error: character string buffer too small" error back.  It seems that the str variable should hold the long string as it is a clob variable.  I was forced to break the string being entered into the "str" clob variable up into chunks because I was getting a "String literal too long for CLOB" error before.  However it now seems that the variable "str" is not being recognized as a clob and I am a limited by the varchar2 length max limitation.  Any help is much appreciated.  The character length of the str variable is 80,000.

```
    example data real array is much longer 
    sqlLineArray = [-107.67346538 47.88608515, -107.67240372 47.88971443, -107.67122833 47.89342082, -107.67126488 47.89706066, -107.67198103 47.90075708]

    s = ', '.join(sqlLineArray)
    l = s.split()
    n = 250
    array = [' '.join(l[x:x+n]) for x in xrange(0, len(l), n)]

"declare
 in_themeid number := "+str(themeInfoObjId)+";
 in_featurename varchar2(100) := '"+replaceApostrophes(row[2])+"';
 str clob;
 p_nextRowId number;
begin
 SAVEPOINT starting_point;
 str := 'linestring (' || '"+"'  ||  '".join(array)+"'||')';
 p_nextRowId := sde.version_user_ddl.next_row_id('REFRNC', "+getTableId('FWPMAPPERLINES', 'REFRNC')+");
 INSERT INTO FWPMAPPERLINES (OBJECTID, REFRNC_ID, FEATURENAME, SHAPE) VALUES
  (p_nextRowId,in_themeid, in_featurename, sde.st_transform(sde.ST_LineFromText(str,82),2));
 commit;
END;"
```

Comment: You're forming a (very, apparently) long string on the fly, and then assigning that long string to the `clob`. I don't think it's the assignment that's the problem, I think it's failing before that. Assuming that's the erroring line, and `row[2]` isn't long too, for example. Not sure why you're using an anonymous block though; why not do a simple insert as a prepared statement and set the `clob` parameter directly?

Comment: The trace back informs me that it is indeed failing on line 8 of the code and row[2] is not to long.  I am not a sql expert so am not sure what you mean by  "insert as a prepared statement and set the clob parameter directly".  When I try to input the string directly into the insert statement or the clob, I get the error "string literal too long".  I have to break the string into chunks  using || to get past this error. The code I posted works until the "str" string variable gets to large.

Comment: Right, but you're concatenating the shorter strings into a long one, and at some point that concatenated string (`varchar2`) exceeds 32k, still before it's assigned to the `clob`. Where are you using this snippet - looks like maybe Java or C#? Can you show how you're calling it and maybe we can figure out how to pass a `clob` directly via `jdbc` or `odbc` or whatever.

Comment: I edited my code.  I am using python with the cxOracle modual to interact with the database. The original array is a series on lat long pairs that make up a line. I have tried to manipulate n to change the chunk sizes, but it still returns the same error.

Comment: I don't use that so I can't help much, but it certainly seems to be possible to [insert a CLOB directly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13706156/266304). Maybe that will give you some pointers.